# Ubuntu Studio 21.10 install fail

Tags: system-installation

I have a new drive for a new install. This is the error I keep getting. [This the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3zJ1.png)

Manual step is really confusing, I am pushing for a default install.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to manually partition? If this is a brand new hard drive, have you formatted it?  You can use the "Disks" application to format the new drive. Just select "Try Ubuntu" to load a live session.  Once the drive is formatted, you should get a guided installation.  You do not need to add partitions, just click the drive, choose "Format" and choose GPT when asked.

Comment: I manually put in /boot/efi 300 Mib  Then I  set it up with / for the rest. An it is now installing.  Thank you for your support.